# Using a Set Iterator in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, set, dereference

When I try to use a set iterator in debug mode in C++, I get an error that says "map/set iterator not dereferencable". I don't understand because I thought dereferincing was how you are supposed to use an iterator. The code looks like this:

```
set<int>::iterator myIterator;
for(myIterator = mySet.begin();
    myIterator != mySet.end();
    myIterator++)
    DoSomething(*myIterator)
```

That is the format of all the examples I have seen online about how to use iterators. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's DoSomething declared as?

Comment: This example looks plausibly correct (barring a missing `;`). You need to post something more complete which actually exhibits the problem that you are having. How is `mySet` filled, for example?

Comment: Is it a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: While it likely doesn't make a difference in this case, you might get better performance with: `++myIterator`. The postfix operator requires making a copy of the iterator.

Comment: Instead of showing what the code "looks like", show us what the code actually is.

Also it is preferred to use pre-increment rather than post-increment on iterators, due to post-increment necessitating the creation of a pointless temporary.

Comment: Dammit GMan! Beat me by 9 seconds.

Answer (score 7):

If `DoSomething()` changes the set - removes or inserts items, then the iterator you're holding is invalidated, which will probably cause this error.

Comment: Only slightly true: a `std::set` iterator is invalidated only if the item to which it refers is removed from the set: you can insert any item, and remove any item but one.  See 23.1.2/8.

Answer (score 2):

The first and biggest thing you're doing wrong is writing code like this at all. What you have above is the manually-written equivalent of:

```
std::for_each(mySet.begin(), mySet.end(), DoSomething);
```

There are relatively few really good uses of iterators outside of implementing algorithms. Once in a while it's reasonable with a map or multimap (or unordered_[multi]map), but that's mostly compensating for map and multimap using std::pair, which isn't entirely wonderful.

Comment: If you're that determined to avoid writing a loop, you can use `unary_compose`, together with a function which maps a pair to its first or second element.

Answer (score 1):

That error generally means you are accessing an "end()" iterator.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that could be the case here, given the loop's conditions. I might be wrong, though: if I'm wrong, could someone please give me a small example or explanation? Thanks.

Comment: Platinum: The actual code in the question isn't what he's running, it's just his impression ("looks like").

Answer (score 1):

This question was based on a false premise. I saw the error "map/set iterator not dereferencable" and thought that that was a general statement that applied to all map/set iterators, which like I said wouldn't make any sense. But I looked again and the real problem was just that the pointer I was using to access that iterator was invalid.